# String comparison from nested for returns always false

Tags: bash, unix, sh

The main issue is that i try to parse ls to do a mock "Compare directories" but when i do so since i use nested fors i cant properly compare the results from it since the comparison of two filenames/strings even if they are the same it always returns false

I tried erasing the white characters but no results.

```
var1=$(ls -l $1 | grep -v ^d | tail -n +2 | tr -s " "| cut -d " " -f 9)
var2=$(ls -l $2 | grep -v ^d | tail -n +2 | tr -s " "| cut -d " " -f 9)

for i in $var1 ; do
    i=$(printf "$i" | tr -d '[:space:]')
    flag=0
    var3=$(ls -l $1 | grep -v ^d | tail -n +2 | tr -s " " | grep $i | cut -d " " -f 5)
        for j in $var2 ; do
        j=$(printf $j | tr -d '[:space:]')
                var4=$(ls -l $2 | grep -v ^d | tail -n +2 | tr -s " " | grep $j | cut -d " " -f 5)
                if [ "$i" == "$j" ] ; then
                        if [ "$var3" != "$var4" ] ; then
                                flag=1
                        fi
                else
            flag=1
        fi
        done
    if [ $flag -eq 1 ] ; then
        printf "$i file does not exist on the $2 catalog\n"
        printf "It 's size is :$var3 \n"
        let Sum=$Sum+$var3
    fi
done
```

Comment: Consider running your code through http://shellcheck.net/ and fixing what it finds before posting here. Additional to what http://shellcheck.net/ will point out, note that `==` is not guaranteed to work in `[`; the only POSIX-standardized string comparison operator is `=`. Similarly, `let` is ancient 1970s syntax, in shells following the 1991 POSIX sh standard, the preferred way to do math is `Sum=$(( Sum + var3 ))`. And see [Why you shouldn't parse the output of `ls`](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs).

Comment: BTW, using `bash -x yourscript` will give you a trace of each command the script runs, which gives you something you can look at to figure out what's going on wrt. logic bugs.

Comment: (As another aside -- when using `printf`, your format string should be constant. If you want to use parameter expansions, put them in later arguments; so, for example: `printf '%s\n' "$i file does not exist on the $2 catalog" "Its size is: $var3"` -- there, the format string is `%s\n`, and you pass two lines, each of which is substituted into the `%s` placeholder in turn).

Comment: ...see also the [APPLICATION USAGE of the POSIX spec for `echo`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/echo.html) for a description of how you're *supposed* to use `printf` as an `echo` replacement, conforming with the advice above (which is to say, using a constant format string).

Comment: for charles : i did use set -x to debug my script to begin with but since it was logical error i could not see it through , a fellow did inform me bellow about it clarifying my mistake and pointing it out. Thanks for the heads up from all of you none the less

Comment: If you read the `set -x` log, why didn't you see the `flag=1` line being run, and look at the comparison before it, and thus understand *why* that line was running? Analyzing a trace of execution is one of the best ways to debug logic errors.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not a string comparison problem, it's a logic problem.

I wrote you [a MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates the same problem with less code and fewer dependencies:

```
flag=0
target="hello"
for candidate in "hello" "world"
do
    if [ "$target" != "$candidate" ]
    then
      flag=1
    fi
done
if [ "$flag" -eq 1 ]
then
  echo "The string was not found"
fi
```

This prints `The string was not found` every time, just like your script, even though it's clearly there.

The problem here is that the script requires that ALL files match. It should only require that ANY file matches. The easiest way to fix this is to:

1. Set `flag=1` when a MATCH is found (not a mismatch)
2. Make `flag=1` signify that a match was found (rather than no match was found)

Here's the version which correctly finds the string:

```
flag=0
target="hello"
for candidate in "hello" "world"
do
    if [ "$target" = "$candidate" ]
    then
      flag=1
    fi
done
if [ "$flag" -eq 1 ]
then
  echo "The string was found"
else
  echo "The string was not found"
fi
```

Comment: You might consider quoting the expansion of `$flag` to be demonstrating good form -- sure, it can't ever be an empty string (or a glob) in the present case, but we *are* a teaching resource.